# How to test if SYN and FIN are both dropped at the same time in hping3?

Tags: iptables

One of the rules to prevent unexpected attack is to prevent SYN & FIN being used together.

## SYN and FIN are both set

$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN -j DROP

How do I use hping to test if this iptable rule works?
*hping3 192.168.7.0 --keep -S -F*???
Is this complete?

When just type *iptables -L*, it shows:

Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN/FIN,SYN

WHY do I need to put the "SYN,FIN" twice before drop?
Is it because one for source and one for destination?

Comment: It's not a prevention unless your TCP/IP stack is lousy; merely a detection (only if you check counters/logs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use nmap:

```
# nmap --scanflags SYN,FIN HOSTNAME
# iptables -nv -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 866K packets, 457M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  120  5280 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x03/0x03
```

Comment: @snow -n options resolve flags to numeric(FIN=0x01,SYN=0x02 SYN+FIN=0x03) See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure